# Splitting One Row into Many Based on Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a table formatted like the one below, i want to split it up so theres a column for month and year ie. January 2014 then another column for cost. So effectively each row would be split into 12 different rows, but i cant for the life of me figure out how to approach it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Line14(
    ItemID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Detail nvarchar(max) NULL,
    Type nvarchar(255) NULL,
    Cat nvarchar(255) NULL,
    Jan_14 money NULL,
    Feb_14 money NULL,
    Mar_14 money NULL,
    Apr_14 money NULL,
    May_14 money NULL,
    Jun_14 money NULL,
    Jul_14 money NULL,
    Aug_14 money NULL,
    Sep_14 money NULL,
    Oct_14 money NULL,
    Nov_14 money NULL,
    Dec_14 money NULL
) ON PRIMARY TEXTIMAGE_ON PRIMARY
GO
```

Comment: Which SQL Server version you are using?

Comment: 2012 but i have access to 2008 as well

Comment: Are Detail, Type and Cat going to be different for each year month pairing? If not that's a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function which converts the data from columns into rows:

```
select itemid,
  detail,
  type,
  cat,
  Month,
  2014 as Year,
  value
from Line14
unpivot
(
  value
  for Month in (Jan_14, Feb_14, Mar_14, Apr_14,
                May_14, Jun_14, Jul_14, Aug_14,
                Sep_14, Oct_14, Nov_14, Dec_14)
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b4b6a/1).

The result would be similar to this:

```
| ITEMID | DETAIL | TYPE |  CAT |  MONTH | YEAR | VALUE |
---------------------------------------------------------
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Jan_14 | 2014 |    10 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Feb_14 | 2014 |    12 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Mar_14 | 2014 |    45 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Apr_14 | 2014 |    56 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | May_14 | 2014 |    89 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Jun_14 | 2014 |    78 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Jul_14 | 2014 |    96 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Aug_14 | 2014 |    35 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Sep_14 | 2014 |    55 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Oct_14 | 2014 |    30 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Nov_14 | 2014 |    99 |
|      1 |   Test |    C | blah | Dec_14 | 2014 |   120 |
```

Comment: never seen that function, awesome again this community is so knowledgeable! cheers

Comment: @user1902540 Happy the help. The `UNPIVOT` function is used when you have a a table that is de-normalized and you want to normalize the data.

Answer (score 0):

build the new table as you describe - then write 12 `insert as select` statements grabbing each month's money value and hardcoding the month value.

Comment: fair enough, i tend to make things a bit more complicated than i should